# Rotate the text of chart with the chart Android

Tags: android, pie-chart

I need your expertise to get out of this problem.
I have used the code given bellow to draw apie chart and rotate it when the flag "bisSmart" is set to true.
   Everything is going fine except one problem.

I want to move the text with it's arc. But the problem is that while moving the text it comes on the chart. I want to move the text from outside of the pie chart.
Plz help me to get out of this problem. Advance thanks.
Here is the code.

```
    public class PieChart extends ViewGroup
    {
        private List<Item> mData = new ArrayList<Item>();
        private float mTotal = 0.0f;
        private RectF mPieBounds = new RectF();
        private Paint mPiePaint;
        private Paint mTextPaint;
        private Paint mShadowPaint;
        private boolean mShowText = false;
        private float mTextX = 0.0f;
        private float mTextY = 0.0f;
        private float mTextWidth = 0.0f;
        private float mTextHeight = 0.0f;
        private int mTextPos = TEXTPOS_LEFT;
        private float mHighlightStrength = 1.15f;
        private float mPointerRadius = 2.0f;
        private float mPointerX;
        private float mPointerY;
        private int mPieRotation;
        private int margin = 0;
        private OnCurrentItemChangedListener mCurrentItemChangedListener = null;
    private int mTextColor;
        private PieView mPieView;
        private Scroller mScroller;
        private ValueAnimator mScrollAnimator;
        private GestureDetector mDetector;
        private PointerView mPointerView;
        private int mCurrentItemAngle;
    private int mCurrentItem = 0;
        private boolean mAutoCenterInSlice;
        private ObjectAnimator mAutoCenterAnimator;
        private RectF mShadowBounds = new RectF();
        private Context cntxPie;
        float rotatedangle = (float) 0.0;
        public static final int TEXTPOS_LEFT = 0;
        public static final int TEXTPOS_RIGHT = 1;
        public static final int FLING_VELOCITY_DOWNSCALE = 4;
        public static final int AUTOCENTER_ANIM_DURATION = 250;
        boolean bisSmart;

        public interface OnCurrentItemChangedListener
            {
                void OnCurrentItemChanged(PieChart source, int currentItem);
            }
        public PieChart(Context context)
            {
                super(context);
                cntxPie = context;
                init();
            }

        public void isSmart(boolean bisSmart)
            {
                this.bisSmart = bisSmart;
            }

        public PieChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
            {
                super(context, attrs);

                TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PieChart, 0, 0);

                try
                    {
                        mShowText = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.PieChart_showText, false);
                        mTextY = a.getDimension(R.styleable.PieChart_labelY, 0.0f);
                        mTextWidth = a.getDimension(R.styleable.PieChart_labelWidth, 0.0f);
                        mTextHeight = a.getDimension(R.styleable.PieChart_labelHeight, 0.0f);
                        mTextPos = a.getInteger(R.styleable.PieChart_labelPosition, 0);
                        mTextColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.PieChart_labelColor, 0xff000000);
                        mHighlightStrength = a.getFloat(R.styleable.PieChart_highlightStrength, 1.0f);
                        mPieRotation = a.getInt(R.styleable.PieChart_pieRotation, 0);
                        mPointerRadius = a.getDimension(R.styleable.PieChart_pointerRadius, 2.0f);
                        mAutoCenterInSlice = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.PieChart_autoCenterPointerInSlice, false);
                    }
                finally
                    {
                        a.recycle();
                    }

                init();
            }


        public boolean getShowText()
            {
                return mShowText;
            }


        public void setShowText(boolean showText)
            {
                mShowText = showText;
                invalidate();
            }

        public float getTextY()
            {
                return mTextY;
            }


        public void setTextY(float textY)
            {
                mTextY = textY;
                invalidate();
            }


        public float getTextWidth()
            {
                return mTextWidth;
            }

        public void setTextWidth(float textWidth)
            {
                mTextWidth = textWidth;
                invalidate();
            }

        public float getTextHeight()
            {
                return mTextHeight;
            }


        public void setTextHeight(float textHeight)
            {
                mTextHeight = textHeight;
                invalidate();
            }

        public int getTextPos()
            {
                return mTextPos;
            }

        public void setTextPos(int textPos)
            {
                if (textPos != TEXTPOS_LEFT && textPos != TEXTPOS_RIGHT)
                    {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("TextPos must be one of TEXTPOS_LEFT or TEXTPOS_RIGHT");
                    }
                mTextPos = textPos;
                invalidate();
            }

        public float getHighlightStrength()
            {
                return mHighlightStrength;
            }


        public void setHighlightStrength(float highlightStrength)
            {
                if (highlightStrength < 0.0f)
                    {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("highlight strength cannot be negative");
                    }
                mHighlightStrength = highlightStrength;
                invalidate();
            }


        public float getPointerRadius()
            {
                return mPointerRadius;
            }


        public void setPointerRadius(float pointerRadius)
            {
                mPointerRadius = pointerRadius;
                invalidate();
            }


        public int getPieRotation()
            {
                return mPieRotation;
            }

        public void setPieRotation(int rotation)
            {
                rotation = (rotation % 360 + 360) % 360;
                mPieRotation = rotation;
                mPieView.rotateTo(rotation);

                calcCurrentItem();
            }

        public int getCurrentItem()
            {
                return mCurrentItem;
            }

        public void setCurrentItem(int currentItem)
            {
                setCurrentItem(currentItem, true);
            }

        private void setCurrentItem(int currentItem, boolean scrollIntoView)
            {
                mCurrentItem = currentItem;
                if (mCurrentItemChangedListener != null)
                    {
                        mCurrentItemChangedListener.OnCurrentItemChanged(this, currentItem);
                    }
                if (scrollIntoView)
                    {
                        centerOnCurrentItem();
                    }
                invalidate();
            }

        public void setOnCurrentItemChangedListener(OnCurrentItemChangedListener listener)
            {
                mCurrentItemChangedListener = listener;
            }


        public int addItem(String label, double value, int color)
            {
                Item it = new Item();
                it.mLabel = label;
                it.mColor = color;
                it.mValue = value;


                it.mHighlight = Color.argb(0xff, Math.min((int) (mHighlightStrength * (float) Color.red(color)), 0xff),
                        Math.min((int) (mHighlightStrength * (float) Color.green(color)), 0xff),
                        Math.min((int) (mHighlightStrength * (float) Color.blue(color)), 0xff));
                mTotal += value;

                mData.add(it);

                onDataChanged();

                return mData.size() - 1;
            }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
            {
                if (bisSmart)
                    {

                        boolean result = mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);


                        if (!result)
                            {
                                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                                    {

                                        stopScrolling();
                                        result = true;
                                    }
                            }
                        return result;
                    }
                return false;
            }

        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
            {

            }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
            {
                super.onDraw(canvas);
                canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                // Draw the shadow
                canvas.drawOval(mShadowBounds, mShadowPaint);

                // Draw the label text
                if (getShowText())
                    {
                        canvas.drawText(mData.get(mCurrentItem).mLabel, mTextX + (mTextX / 2), getHeight() / 2, mTextPaint);
                    }


                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
                    {
                        tickScrollAnimation();
                        if (!mScroller.isFinished())
                            {
                                postInvalidate();
                            }
                    }
            }


        @Override
        protected int getSuggestedMinimumWidth()
            {
                return (int) mTextWidth * 2;
            }

        @Override
        protected int getSuggestedMinimumHeight()
            {
                return (int) mTextWidth;
            }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
            {
                // Try for a width based on our minimum
                int minw = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + getSuggestedMinimumWidth();

                int w = Math.max(minw, MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec));

                // Whatever the width ends up being, ask for a height that would let the pie
                // get as big as it can
                int minh = (w - (int) mTextWidth) + getPaddingBottom() + getPaddingTop();
                int h = Math.min(MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec), minh);

                setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
            }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
            {
                super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);


                float xpad = (float) (getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight());
                float ypad = (float) (getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom());

                // Account for the label
                if (mShowText)
                    xpad += mTextWidth;

                float ww = (float) w - xpad;
                float hh = (float) h - ypad;

                float diameter = Math.min(ww, hh);
                mPieBounds = new RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, diameter, diameter);
                mPieBounds.offsetTo(getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop());

                mPointerY = mTextY - (mTextHeight / 2.0f);
                float pointerOffset = mPieBounds.centerY() - mPointerY;

                mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
                mTextX = mPieBounds.right;

                if (pointerOffset < 0)
                    {
                        pointerOffset = -pointerOffset;
                        mCurrentItemAngle = 360;// 360;//315
                    }
                else
                    {
                        mCurrentItemAngle = 0;// 45
                    }
                mPointerX = mPieBounds.centerX() + pointerOffset;
                // }

                mShadowBounds = new RectF(mPieBounds.left + 10, mPieBounds.bottom + 10, mPieBounds.right - 10, mPieBounds.bottom + 20);


                if (bisSmart)
                    mPieView.layout((int) mPieBounds.left, (int) mPieBounds.top, (int) mPieBounds.right, (int) mPieBounds.bottom);
                else
                    mPieView.layout((int) mPieBounds.left - 40, (int) mPieBounds.top, (int) mPieBounds.right + 60, (int) mPieBounds.bottom);

                mPieView.setPivot(mPieBounds.width() / 2, mPieBounds.height() / 2);

                onDataChanged();
            }


        private void calcCurrentItem()
            {

                // mCurrentItemAngle=-45;
                int pointerAngle = (mCurrentItemAngle + 360 + mPieRotation) % 360;
                for (int i = 0; i < mData.size(); ++i)
                    {
                        Item it = mData.get(i);
                        if (it.mStartAngle <= pointerAngle && pointerAngle <= it.mEndAngle)
                            {
                                if (i != mCurrentItem)
                                    {
                                        setCurrentItem(i, false);
                                    }
                                break;
                            }
                    }
            }


        private void onDataChanged()
            {
                // When the data changes, we have to recalculate
                // all of the angles.
                int currentAngle = 0;
                int count = 0;

                for (Item it : mData)
                    {
                        count++;
                        it.mStartAngle = currentAngle;

                        if (count == mData.size())
                            it.mEndAngle = 360;
                        else
                            it.mEndAngle = (int) ((float) currentAngle + it.mValue * 360.0f / mTotal);

                        currentAngle = it.mEndAngle;


                        it.mShader = new SweepGradient(mPieBounds.width() / 2.0f, mPieBounds.height() / 2.0f, new int[]
                            { it.mHighlight, it.mHighlight, it.mColor, it.mColor, }, new float[]
                            { 0, (float) (360 - it.mEndAngle) / 360.0f, (float) (360 - it.mStartAngle) / 360.0f, 1.0f });
                    }
                calcCurrentItem();
                onScrollFinished();
            }

        private void init()
            {

                setLayerToSW(this);

                // Set up the paint for the label text
                mTextPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
                mTextPaint.setColor(mTextColor);
                if (mTextHeight == 0)
                    {
                        mTextHeight = mTextPaint.getTextSize();
                    }
                else
                    {
                        mTextPaint.setTextSize(mTextHeight);
                    }

                // Set up the paint for the pie slices
                mPiePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
                mPiePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                mPiePaint.setTextSize(mTextHeight);

                // Set up the paint for the shadow
                mShadowPaint = new Paint(0);
                mShadowPaint.setColor(0xff101010);
                mShadowPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));

                mPieView = new PieView(getContext());
                mPieView.measure(800, 800);

                addView(mPieView);
                mPieView.rotateTo(mPieRotation);


                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
                    {
                        mAutoCenterAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(PieChart.this, "PieRotation", 0);

                        // Add a listener to hook the onAnimationEnd event so that we can do
                        // some cleanup when the pie stops moving.
                        mAutoCenterAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener()
                            {
                                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator)
                                    {
                                    }

                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator)
                                    {
                                        mPieView.decelerate();
                                    }

                                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator)
                                    {
                                    }

                                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator)
                                    {
                                    }
                            });
                    }

                // Create a Scroller to handle the fling gesture.
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
                    {
                        mScroller = new Scroller(getContext());
                    }
                else
                    {
                        mScroller = new Scroller(getContext(), null, true);
                    }

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
                    {
                        mScrollAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
                        mScrollAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener()
                            {
                                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator)
                                    {
                                        tickScrollAnimation();
                                    }
                            });
                    }


                mDetector = new GestureDetector(PieChart.this.getContext(), new GestureListener());


                mDetector.setIsLongpressEnabled(false);


                if (this.isInEditMode())
                    {

                    }

            }

        private void tickScrollAnimation()
            {
                if (!mScroller.isFinished())
                    {
                        mScroller.computeScrollOffset();
                        setPieRotation(mScroller.getCurrY());
                    }
                else
                    {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
                            {
                                mScrollAnimator.cancel();
                            }
                        onScrollFinished();
                    }
            }

        private void setLayerToSW(View v)
            {
                if (!v.isInEditMode() && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
                    {
                        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
                    }
            }

        private void setLayerToHW(View v)
            {
                if (!v.isInEditMode() && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
                    {
                        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
                    }
            }


        private void stopScrolling()
            {
                mScroller.forceFinished(true);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
                    {
                        mAutoCenterAnimator.cancel();
                    }

                onScrollFinished();
            }

        private void onScrollFinished()
            {
                if (mAutoCenterInSlice)
                    {
                        centerOnCurrentItem();
                    }
                else
                    {
                        mPieView.decelerate();
                    }
            }

        private void centerOnCurrentItem()
            {
                Item current = mData.get(getCurrentItem());
                int targetAngle = current.mStartAngle + (current.mEndAngle - current.mStartAngle) / 2;
                targetAngle -= mCurrentItemAngle;
                if (targetAngle < 90 && mPieRotation > 180)
                    targetAngle += 360;

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
                    {
                        // Fancy animated version
                        mAutoCenterAnimator.setIntValues(targetAngle);
                        mAutoCenterAnimator.setDuration(AUTOCENTER_ANIM_DURATION).start();
                    }
                else
                    {
                        // Dull non-animated version
                        // mPieView.rotateTo(targetAngle);
                    }
            }


        private class PieView extends View
            {
                private PointF mPivot = new PointF();

                /**
                 * Construct a PieView
                 * 
                 * @param context
                 */
                public PieView(Context context)
                    {
                        super(context);
                        // this.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(300, 300));
                    }

                @Override
                protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
                    {
                        setMeasuredDimension(measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec), measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec));
                        // super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
                        super.onMeasure(800, 800);
                    }

                private int measureWidth(int measureSpec)
                    {
                        int preferred = 800;
                        return getMeasurement(measureSpec, preferred);
                    }

                private int measureHeight(int measureSpec)
                    {
                        int preferred = 800;
                        return getMeasurement(measureSpec, preferred);
                    }

                private int getMeasurement(int measureSpec, int preferred)
                    {
                        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);
                        int measurement = 0;

                        switch (MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec))
                            {
                            case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                                // This means the width of this view has been given.
                                measurement = specSize;
                                break;
                            case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
                                // Take the minimum of the preferred size and what
                                // we were told to be.
                                measurement = Math.min(preferred, specSize);
                                break;
                            default:
                                measurement = preferred;
                                break;
                            }

                        return 800;
                    }


                public void accelerate()
                    {
                        setLayerToHW(this);
                    }


                public void decelerate()
                    {
                        setLayerToSW(this);
                    }

                @Override
                protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
                    {
                        super.onDraw(canvas);

                        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                        int left = 0 + margin;
                        int top = 0 + margin;
                        int right = 0 + getWidth();
                        int bottom = 0 + getHeight();

                        int mRadius = Math.min(Math.abs(right - left), Math.abs(bottom - top));
                        int radius = (int) (mRadius * 0.35 * 1.0);
                        float shortRadius = radius * 0.9f;
                        float longRadius = radius * 1.1f;

                        for (int i = 0; i < mData.size(); i++)
                            {
                                Item it = mData.get(i);
                                mPiePaint.setShader(it.mShader);

                                float fStartAngle = 360 - it.mEndAngle;
                                float fEndAngle = it.mEndAngle - it.mStartAngle;

                                canvas.drawArc(mBounds, fStartAngle, fEndAngle, true, mPiePaint);

                                Paint pntWhite = new Paint();
                                pntWhite.setAntiAlias(true);
                                pntWhite.setColor(Color.parseColor("#EFE7E7"));
                                pntWhite.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
                                if (bisSmart)
                                    pntWhite.setStrokeWidth(3);
                                else
                                    pntWhite.setStrokeWidth(1.5f);

                                canvas.drawArc(mBounds, fStartAngle, fEndAngle, true, pntWhite);

                                Paint pntBlack = new Paint();
                                // Center circle that does not rotate
                                // canvas.save();
                                pntBlack.setAntiAlias(true);
                                pntBlack.setStyle(Style.FILL);
                                pntBlack.setColor(Color.parseColor("#B5B5B5"));
                                if (bisSmart)
                                    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, 60, pntBlack);
                                else
                                    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, 30, pntBlack);

                                // Center circle that does not rotate
                                canvas.save();

                                if (bisSmart)
                                    {
                                        pntWhite.setStrokeWidth(2);
                                        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, 60, pntWhite);
                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                        pntWhite.setStrokeWidth(1.5f);
                                        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, 30, pntWhite);
                                    }

                                canvas.rotate(-mPieRotation, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
                                canvas.restore();
                            }
                        List<RectF> prevLabelsBounds = new ArrayList<RectF>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < mData.size(); i++)
                            {
                                Item it = mData.get(i);

                                float fStartAngle = 360 - it.mEndAngle;
                                float fEndAngle = it.mEndAngle - it.mStartAngle;

                                int color = Color.parseColor("#5A595A");

                                drawLabel(it.mLabel, prevLabelsBounds, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, shortRadius, longRadius, fStartAngle,
                                        fEndAngle, left, right, false, canvas, color);

                            }
                        prevLabelsBounds.clear();
                    }

                @Override
                protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
                    {
                        if (bisSmart)
                            mBounds = new RectF(0 + 90, 0 + 90, w - 90, h - 90);
                        else
                            mBounds = new RectF(0 + 100, 0 + 50, w - 100, h - 50);
                    }

                RectF mBounds;

                public void rotateTo(float pieRotation)
                    {
                        rotatedangle = pieRotation;
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
                            {
                                setRotation(pieRotation);
                                invalidate();
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                invalidate();
                            }
                    }

                public void setPivot(float x, float y)
                    {
                        mPivot.x = x;
                        mPivot.y = y;
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
                            {
                                setPivotX(x);
                                setPivotY(y);
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                invalidate();
                            }
                    }
            }




        private class Item
            {
                public String mLabel;
                public double mValue;
                public int mColor;

                // computed values
                public int mStartAngle;
                public int mEndAngle;

                public int mHighlight;
                public Shader mShader;
            }


        private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
            {
                @Override
                public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
                    {
                        // Set the pie rotation directly.
                        float scrollTheta = vectorToScalarScroll(distanceX, distanceY, e2.getX() - mPieBounds.centerX(),
                                e2.getY() - mPieBounds.centerY());
                        setPieRotation(getPieRotation() - (int) scrollTheta / FLING_VELOCITY_DOWNSCALE);

                        return true;
                    }

                @Override
                public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
                    {
                        // Set up the Scroller for a fling
                        float scrollTheta = vectorToScalarScroll(velocityX, velocityY, e2.getX() - mPieBounds.centerX(),
                                e2.getY() - mPieBounds.centerY());
                        mScroller.fling(0, (int) getPieRotation(), 0, (int) scrollTheta / FLING_VELOCITY_DOWNSCALE, 0, 0, Integer.MIN_VALUE,
                                Integer.MAX_VALUE);

                        // Start the animator and tell it to animate for the expected duration of the fling.
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
                            {
                                mScrollAnimator.setDuration(mScroller.getDuration());
                                mScrollAnimator.start();
                            }
                        return true;
                    }

                @Override
                public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e)
                    {
                        // The user is interacting with the pie, so we want to turn on acceleration
                        // so that the interaction is smooth.
                        mPieView.accelerate();
                        if (isAnimationRunning())
                            {
                                stopScrolling();
                            }
                        return true;
                    }
            }

        private boolean isAnimationRunning()
            {
                return !mScroller.isFinished() || (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11 && mAutoCenterAnimator.isRunning());
            }


        private static float vectorToScalarScroll(float dx, float dy, float x, float y)
            {

                float l = (float) Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                float crossX = -y;
                float crossY = x;

                float dot = (crossX * dx + crossY * dy);
                float sign = Math.signum(dot);

                return l * sign;
            }

        protected void drawLabel(String labelText, List<RectF> prevLabelsBounds, int centerX, int centerY, float shortRadius, float longRadius,
                float currentAngle, float angle, int left, int right, boolean line, Canvas mcanvas, int txtcolor)
            {
                // line=true;
                Paint pntText = new Paint();
                pntText.setAntiAlias(true);
                pntText.setColor(txtcolor);
                if (bisSmart)
                    pntText.setTextSize(15);
                else
                    pntText.setTextSize(10);

                double rAngle = Math.toRadians(90 - (currentAngle + angle / 2));
                double sinValue = Math.sin(rAngle);
                double cosValue = Math.cos(rAngle);
                int x1 = Math.round(centerX + (float) (shortRadius * sinValue));
                int y1 = Math.round(centerY + (float) (shortRadius * cosValue));
                int x2 = Math.round(centerX + (float) (longRadius * sinValue));
                int y2 = Math.round(centerY + (float) (longRadius * cosValue));

                float size = 20;
                float extra = Math.max(size / 2, 10);
                pntText.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
                if (x1 > x2)
                    {
                        extra = -extra;
                    }

                float xLabel = x2 + extra;
                float yLabel = y2;
                // labelText = getFitText(labelText, width, paint);
                float widthLabel = pntText.measureText(labelText);
                boolean okBounds = false;
                while (!okBounds && line)
                    {
                        boolean intersects = false;
                        int length = prevLabelsBounds.size();
                        for (int j = 0; j < length && !intersects; j++)
                            {
                                RectF prevLabelBounds = prevLabelsBounds.get(j);
                                if (prevLabelBounds.intersects(xLabel, yLabel, xLabel + widthLabel, yLabel + size))
                                    {
                                        intersects = true;
                                        yLabel = Math.max(yLabel, prevLabelBounds.bottom);
                                    }
                            }
                        okBounds = !intersects;
                    }

                if (line)
                    {
                        y2 = (int) (yLabel - size / 2);
                        mcanvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, pntText);
                    }
                else
                    {
                        pntText.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
                    }
                /**
                 * my code
                 */
                // draw bounding rect before rotating text
                Rect rect = new Rect();
                pntText.getTextBounds(labelText, 0, labelText.length(), rect);
                mcanvas.save();

                // rotate the canvas on center of the text to draw

                mcanvas.rotate(-mPieRotation, xLabel, yLabel);

                if (bisSmart)
                    {
                        mcanvas.drawText(labelText, xLabel, yLabel, pntText);
                        /*
                         * if (x1 > x2) { //pntText.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT); mcanvas.drawText(labelText, xLabel-(widthLabel / 3) , yLabel, pntText); } else { //pntText.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
                         * mcanvas.drawText(labelText, xLabel + (widthLabel / 3), yLabel, pntText); }
                         */
                    }
                else
                    {
                        if (xLabel < centerX)
                            {

                                mcanvas.drawText(labelText, xLabel - (widthLabel / 3), yLabel, pntText);
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                mcanvas.drawText(labelText, xLabel + (widthLabel / 3), yLabel, pntText);
                            }
                    }

                mcanvas.restore();
                if (line)
                    {
                        prevLabelsBounds.add(new RectF(xLabel, yLabel, xLabel + widthLabel, yLabel + size));
                    }

            }
    }
```

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: Hey chirag I have formatted the code plz help me.